# Limit search results based on field in list

Tags: 2010, search, search-scope, managed-property, crawled-property

My search basically just has one scope to crawl everything. Can someone provide me with brief overview or link to guide to:

1. setup a new scope to filter results
2. Setup managed and crawled properties for field to exclude on
3. set the value of such field for the exclusion.

What I am trying to do is exclude search results on a list based on a value of a field. For example we have a list called catalog which contains seasonal items. When it is not that items season, its status field is set to inactive.

1. So how do I go about creating a scope to look at status property and exclude result when it is inactive?
2. Is this managed property something I could add other crawled property "statuses" to so that I may exclude "inactive" things on other lists in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your questions:

1. You create your query like:

   {searchboxquery} status:active

   For that you need of course a Managed Property (create it in the
   Search Service Application and map the values of your custom column
   to it. The custom column creates a crawled property once it was
   crawled usually prefixed with ows_ followed by the columns name).
   So when you search the {searchboxquery} will be replaced with the query from the textbox
   and the status:active limits the results to items with a property called status and the value active.
2. The managed property is filled per item - not once per farm or something. You could do that, too - but I think that is not what you want.